# Is it possible to set the default value of an integer sharedpreference as an empty field?

Tags: android, integer, default-value, android-sharedpreferences

I'm using SharedPreferences to save multiple values from multiple Activities and Fragments and reuse them in various others. This works fine so far. 
I mostly save Integers. Is it possible to set the default value of such a SharedPreference to be empty, so when the value is shown in a TextView, the TextView will be empty? 
I want this for user convenience, so the user doesn't have to delete the default value in the field, if he wants to change it.

Here is an example of what I mean:

```js
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("Datenspeicher", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        int Stk_jahr = sharedPref.getInt("sp_stueckzahl", 0);
    
        Stueckzahl.setText(String.valueOf(Stk_jahr));
```

In this example, if no value is saved in sp_stueckzahl, die TextView Stueckzahl will show a 0. I would prefer it to be empty.

Thank you

Comment: don't set the text if value is 0

Comment: `int` can't be *empty*. It can be only a number. But you can check if `sharedPref` has value for key `sp_stueckzahl`, and if it has not - don't set text into TextView

Comment: save number as string if needed parse it to integer. force user to enter only numbers.

Comment: Or you can use `Stueckzahl.setText(String.valueOf(Stk_jahr != 0 ? Stk_jahr : ""));`

Comment: @SonTruong: Thank you very much. It worked perfectly and was fast to implement.